# Entity Framework 1:0-1 relationships pluralize child entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I've noticed that when you create a 1:1 relationship in EF (I'm using 4.3), the child entity is pluralized (or pluralised), even when the maximum related rows is 1.

I've found a post that alludes to this but doesn't say why this is the case, or if there is a fixed version or workaround.

Anyone know more?

Comment: +1 for including the British spelling!